# Sklearm and Matplotlib, exporting a multi-subplot plot to HTML

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the `silhouette_score` metric in sklearn to evaluate my KMeans model. I am using matplotlib to produce and export the entire plot into HTML that is going to be viewed in a client-side code (a dashboard). I noticed that my code (modified from sklearn's docs) generates only the last subplot and not the entire plot.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import base64
from io import BytesIO


print(__doc__)

    # Generating the sample data from make_blobs
    # This particular setting has one distinct cluster and 3 clusters placed close
    # together.
def silhouette(X, range_n_clusters=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]):

    for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
        # Create a subplot with 1 row and 2 columns
        fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
        fig.set_size_inches(18, 7)

        # The 1st subplot is the silhouette plot
        # The silhouette coefficient can range from -1, 1 but in this example all
        # lie within [-0.1, 1]
        ax1.set_xlim([-0.1, 1])
        # The (n_clusters+1)*10 is for inserting blank space between silhouette
        # plots of individual clusters, to demarcate them clearly.
        ax1.set_ylim([0, len(X) + (n_clusters + 1) * 10])

        # Initialize the clusterer with n_clusters value and a random generator
        # seed of 10 for reproducibility.
        clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=10)
        cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(X)
        print(cluster_labels, 36)
        # The silhouette_score gives the average value for all the samples.
        # This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
        # clusters
        silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, cluster_labels)
        print("For n_clusters =", n_clusters,
            "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)

        # Compute the silhouette scores for each sample
        sample_silhouette_values = silhouette_samples(X, cluster_labels)

        y_lower = 10
        for i in range(n_clusters):
            # Aggregate the silhouette scores for samples belonging to
            # cluster i, and sort them
            ith_cluster_silhouette_values = \
                sample_silhouette_values[cluster_labels == i]

            ith_cluster_silhouette_values.sort()

            size_cluster_i = ith_cluster_silhouette_values.shape[0]
            y_upper = y_lower + size_cluster_i

            color = cm.nipy_spectral(float(i) / n_clusters)
            ax1.fill_betweenx(np.arange(y_lower, y_upper),
                            0, ith_cluster_silhouette_values,
                            facecolor=color, edgecolor=color, alpha=0.7)

            # Label the silhouette plots with their cluster numbers at the middle
            ax1.text(-0.05, y_lower + 0.5 * size_cluster_i, str(i))

            # Compute the new y_lower for next plot
            y_lower = y_upper + 10  # 10 for the 0 samples

        ax1.set_title("The silhouette plot for the various clusters.")
        ax1.set_xlabel("The silhouette coefficient values")
        ax1.set_ylabel("Cluster label")

        # The vertical line for average silhouette score of all the values
        ax1.axvline(x=silhouette_avg, color="red", linestyle="--")

        ax1.set_yticks([])  # Clear the yaxis labels / ticks
        ax1.set_xticks([-0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])

        # 2nd Plot showing the actual clusters formed
        colors = cm.nipy_spectral(cluster_labels.astype(float) / n_clusters)
        ax2.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker='.', s=30, lw=0, alpha=0.7,
                    c=colors, edgecolor='k')

        # Labeling the clusters
        centers = clusterer.cluster_centers_
        # Draw white circles at cluster centers
        ax2.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], marker='o',
                    c="white", alpha=1, s=200, edgecolor='k')

        for i, c in enumerate(centers):
            ax2.scatter(c[0], c[1], marker='$%d$' % i, alpha=1,
                        s=50, edgecolor='k')

        ax2.set_title("The visualization of the clustered data.")
        ax2.set_xlabel("Feature space for the 1st feature")
        ax2.set_ylabel("Feature space for the 2nd feature")

        plt.suptitle(("Silhouette analysis for KMeans clustering on sample data "
                    "with n_clusters = %d" % n_clusters),
                    fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

    tmpfile = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(tmpfile, format='png')
    encoded = base64.b64encode(tmpfile.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
    html = '<img src=\'data:image/png;base64,{}\'>'.format(encoded)
    return html
```

Any ideas on how to export the entire plot and what is missing on the upper snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had to use fig instead of plot to solve the problem. Here is how:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import base64
from io import BytesIO


print(__doc__)

    # Generating the sample data from make_blobs
    # This particular setting has one distinct cluster and 3 clusters placed close
    # together.
def silhouette(X, range_n_clusters=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]):
    plts = []
    for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
        # Create a subplot with 1 row and 2 columns
        fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
        fig.set_size_inches(18, 7)

        # The 1st subplot is the silhouette plot
        # The silhouette coefficient can range from -1, 1 but in this example all
        # lie within [-0.1, 1]
        ax1.set_xlim([-0.1, 1])
        # The (n_clusters+1)*10 is for inserting blank space between silhouette
        # plots of individual clusters, to demarcate them clearly.
        ax1.set_ylim([0, len(X) + (n_clusters + 1) * 10])

        # Initialize the clusterer with n_clusters value and a random generator
        # seed of 10 for reproducibility.
        clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=10)
        cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(X)
        print(cluster_labels, 36)
        # The silhouette_score gives the average value for all the samples.
        # This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
        # clusters
        silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, cluster_labels)
        print("For n_clusters =", n_clusters,
            "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)

        # Compute the silhouette scores for each sample
        sample_silhouette_values = silhouette_samples(X, cluster_labels)

        y_lower = 10
        for i in range(n_clusters):
            # Aggregate the silhouette scores for samples belonging to
            # cluster i, and sort them
            ith_cluster_silhouette_values = \
                sample_silhouette_values[cluster_labels == i]

            ith_cluster_silhouette_values.sort()

            size_cluster_i = ith_cluster_silhouette_values.shape[0]
            y_upper = y_lower + size_cluster_i

            color = cm.nipy_spectral(float(i) / n_clusters)
            ax1.fill_betweenx(np.arange(y_lower, y_upper),
                            0, ith_cluster_silhouette_values,
                            facecolor=color, edgecolor=color, alpha=0.7)

            # Label the silhouette plots with their cluster numbers at the middle
            ax1.text(-0.05, y_lower + 0.5 * size_cluster_i, str(i))

            # Compute the new y_lower for next plot
            y_lower = y_upper + 10  # 10 for the 0 samples

        ax1.set_title("The silhouette plot for the various clusters.")
        ax1.set_xlabel("The silhouette coefficient values")
        ax1.set_ylabel("Cluster label")

        # The vertical line for average silhouette score of all the values
        ax1.axvline(x=silhouette_avg, color="red", linestyle="--")

        ax1.set_yticks([])  # Clear the yaxis labels / ticks
        ax1.set_xticks([-0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])

        # 2nd Plot showing the actual clusters formed
        colors = cm.nipy_spectral(cluster_labels.astype(float) / n_clusters)
        ax2.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker='.', s=30, lw=0, alpha=0.7,
                    c=colors, edgecolor='k')

        # Labeling the clusters
        centers = clusterer.cluster_centers_
        # Draw white circles at cluster centers
        ax2.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], marker='o',
                    c="white", alpha=1, s=200, edgecolor='k')

        for i, c in enumerate(centers):
            ax2.scatter(c[0], c[1], marker='$%d$' % i, alpha=1,
                        s=50, edgecolor='k')

        ax2.set_title("The visualization of the clustered data.")
        ax2.set_xlabel("Feature space for the 1st feature")
        ax2.set_ylabel("Feature space for the 2nd feature")

        plt.suptitle(("Silhouette analysis for KMeans clustering on sample data "
                    "with n_clusters = %d" % n_clusters),
                    fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

        plts.append(fig)

    results = []
    for fig in plts:
        tmpfile = BytesIO()
        fig.savefig(tmpfile, format='png')
        tmpfile.seek(0)
        encoded = base64.b64encode(tmpfile.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
        html = '<img src=\'data:image/png;base64,{}\'>'.format(encoded)
        results.append(html)
    return results
```